# Cannot convert '#value!" to double

Tags: qgis, error, string

I am trying to convert a string to a numerical format by creating a new field.  I get an error message saying "Cannot convert '#VALUE!' to double."  What does this mean?  [image]

[image]

Answer (score 8):

There are values in the field that can't be converted to a double (a string with letters, wrong decimal separator etc).

Comment: There are no letters, only numbers, commas, and decimal points.  What is most likely causing it?

Comment: There probably shouldn't be any commas. Check for values that are just spaces as well.

Answer (score 7):

Try this and see if you can find the feature(s) causing the error:

```
lyr = iface.activeLayer() #Click the layer in layer tree

error_rows = []
for f in lyr.getFeatures():
    try:
        float(f['LAN_KOD']) #Change LAN_KOD to match your fieldname
    except (ValueError, TypeError) as e:
        lyr.select(f.id())
        error_rows.append([f.id(), e])

for row in error_rows:
    print(row[0], row[1])
```

[image]